# aggregate list of countries by continents

Tags: r

[image]

Is that possible to list out all the countries of one continent to this type of data. If yes, please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `countrycode` package

```r
library(dplyr)
library(countrycode)

df %>%
  #add a column having corresponding continent name in 'Continent' column
  mutate(Continent = countrycode(Country, 'country.name', 'continent')) %>%   
  group_by(Continent) %>%
  #aggregation based on Continent 
  summarise(Random_col_Mean = mean(Random_col))
```

which gives

```
  Continent Random_col_Mean
1 Americas              500
2 Asia                  600
3 Europe                222
```

**Sample data:** (In absence of reproducible example I have considered below data for the demonstration purpose)

```
df <- structure(list(Country = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 
4L), .Label = c("Belgium", "Croatia", "France", "Japan", "Mexico", 
"UK"), class = "factor"), Random_col = c(100, 111, 200, 300, 
400, 500, 600)), .Names = c("Country", "Random_col"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")

  Country Random_col
1  France        100
2  France        111
3 Belgium        200
4      UK        300
5 Croatia        400
6  Mexico        500
7   Japan        600
```